# how to print a document from android device to wifi printers

Tags: java, android

i was trying to create an android app that creates a pdf and send to wifi printers.Is it possible if i have a specific printer driver installed in my phone .If so how to do that.Or please suggest a way to print to any wifi prin ters

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html

Comment: i have a doubt...while using print manager,is it using google cloud printing?

Comment: No. That is a separate system. Android 4.4+ has its own built-in printing framework.

Comment: thank you..u have cleared my doubt...and i got it worked:)